# How to make an auto hiding menu bar with Qt4

Tags: animation, qt4, menubar

I am trying to make a Qt application which has an auto hiding menu bar. How can i do that?

Comment: Can you give more detail about the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: I want menu bar to appear only when mouse cursor is between 0-50 pixels of program area vertically, if not then hide itself automatically. Like windows task bar auto hide function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting task ! Ok, lets see... I'd suggest you putting a code that keeps track of mouse cursor movement in [QMainWindow::centralWidget()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget). You need to call [QWidget::setMouseTracking(true)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) first to be able to keep track of your mouse movement (they are turned off by default). The code can look like this:

```
QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow;
MyWidget * myWidget = new MyWidget(mainWindow);
myWidget->setMouseTracking(true);
mainWindow->setCentralWidget(myWidget);
```

And then in your widget QWidget::mouseMove() event you need to detect whether you are in the correct area. The code can look like this:

```
void MyWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event) {
    bool menuVisible = inCorrectArea(event->pos());
    mainWindow->menuBar()->setVisible(menuVisible);
    ...
}
```

There are several ways to get access to "mainWindow" in your MyWidget. One of them is to store a pointer in MyWidget private variable when you pass MainWindow in its  MyWidget constructor. You can also issue a signal from your MyWidget and handle it in MainWindow.

Hope this helps.